# Dynamic query to load a table based on assigned weightage

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a source table Articles with 1000 records for furniture articles. Below are the records for each category.

```
Beds    150
Sofa    350
Chairs  250
Tables  250
```

I want to select 25 articles from each category every day and load the 100 articles into a Destination table and at the end of 10 days, all the articles will be available in the destination table. After few days of executions, there is no bed left to select from source table. In that case, it should give priority to Sofa and if sofa is finished then chairs and tables. Can anyone give me an idea of achieving it in SQL query? Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand.  Where are you storing the information about which items have already been used?  Is your goal to get a balanced sample each day?  If so, why is it biased toward sofas when you run out of tables?

Comment: Hello Gordon. These are the returned items. The idea is to pick the equal sample from each category and load into a destination table for QA team to check. The data is masked to get the SQL that I can try with the production data. Hope you understand.

Comment: So, after the few days when there are no more beds available - you want 50 sofas, 25 chairs and 25 tables? Or what do you intend with "give priority to sofa"? And what happens during daily business: what happens if more beds / chaurs / ... are returned? I guess the table will never reach a 0-row count since I guess there will be returns on a more or less regular basis, won't there?

Comment: Hello Tyron, yes if there is no beds available then I want 50 sofas, 25 chairs and 25 tables. Order of precedence is 1) beds, 2) Sofa, 3) Chairs, 4) Tables. The source table will be static means there will be no additions unless all is loaded to destination.